# Share on facebook, text doesn't come up on phone. (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, share

I have a 'share on facebook' button in my app. But it doesn't work like i want it to.

i tried different codes but none of them worked on my phone. 
The window pops up and i can share something if i want. But the initialText doesn't show on my iphone, while it does show it on the simulator?
Only on the simulator i get an alert that facebook doesn't work ofcourse.

Anyone know's how to fix this. Or is it even possible?

This is the code i used:

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
            let facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            facebookSheet.setInitialText("\(antwoordTxt.text!)")
            self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't make autoText's to Facebook anymore.. So there's my answer... :p